# Error running gcc on cygwin (bad adress)

Tags: cygwin, gcc

I'm trying to get gcc running on cygwin. Whenever I launch it, I get the error:

```
$ gcc a1.c
gcc: installation problem, cannot exec '/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/cc1.exe': Bad address
gcc: installation problem, cannot exec '/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/collect2.exe': Bad address
```

gcc4 has the same problem. What may be causing this?

Comment: Are you using the rxvt Cygwin terminal? Did you try via a normal Windows command prompt?

Comment: That doesn't make any difference. Installing gcc-4, however, seems to have fixed gcc-3. So my problem is solved but I'm still curious if anyone has an explanation.